# Vaadin - adding components as elements of another components

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I've been using a ComboBox to store some values and make a selection from those values, but the problem is, ComboBox, as it is, only allows one selection at the time and I need multiple selections, ie checkboxes, but that cannot be done via Vaadin. I figured if I could present checkboxes as the elements of the ComboBox, that would solve the issue, except adding components to a component that is not a layout doesn't seem to be possible.

I've done this tutorial https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-customcomponent.html
Basically it combines two Vaadin components into one panel and displays them together, but that's not what I need, as I need certain components to be placed inside a parent component.

So what are my options if I'm to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/comboboxmultiselect-add-on

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question that you are asking (component within a component), but rather the underlying problem that you present. In other words, I believe your question is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I think you want to use a `Grid` with multi-select turned on. In this mode, check boxes are automatically added to each row and there is a checkbox in the header to allow toggling all on/off, ability to filter, ability to sort columns, etc. See [the documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this method.